# How to install python lib mahotas on linux with setup tools

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pip, mahotas

I want to install the python library Mahotas on my Raspberry Pi 2 which runs rasbian, a special version of Debian. However, when I tried to use `sudo apt-get install python-mahotas` I got an error saying that the lib did not exist.

I then downloaded mahotas via the browser in the GUI hoping it would work that way. I unpacked the zip file into `home/pi/Downloads/mahotas-1.4.0/` and ran `python setup.py install` It now returned an error saying that it needed setup tools in order to be installed correctly.

After some research on the internet, I installed those setup tools, using `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`, which were now in the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Setup.py, in the mahotas directory, still said I needed setup tools so I copied the setup tools folder into the mahotas directory thinking that it might solve the problem to get them in the same directory. It did not.

I have googled a lot but I could not solve the problem. Does anyone know what the problem is with my attempts to install mahotas? I am new to linux so it might be something simple but i cannot find any solution.

Update 31-08:

I have tried what Dave suggested in the comments, but after some tries it still didn't work. The first command returned a bunch of 404's . The reason that I at first thought it would still work was because my internet does weird things, sometimes giving an error. That was not the case here I discovered later.

Does  anyone else have a solution?

Comment: sudo pip install mahotas

Comment: I have tried that but it did not recognize pip as a command. Is there something else I need to download first?

Comment: install pip first. 
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv